# Installed tools of services in ubuntu

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04

At first I download cassandra as tar, simply extract it and use without problem with other components such as "nodetool", "cqlsh" was in apache-cassandra2.2.5/bin folder also. But then from [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html) page I have installed cassandra via debian packages and its now running as a service I am able to start and stop it by typing `sudo service cassandra start`

That looks fine but I can't find location of other tools. In previous installation I may run "nodetool" and "cqlsh" with typing "bin/nodetool" and "bin/cqlsh" and also see the data inside cassandra node with /apache-cassandra2.2.5/data/data/keysapce_name/tables.."

That was pretty cool all in one place but now I removed it and installed cassandra 3.0.4 with debian I couldnt find where "nodetool" and "cqlsh" are and how to check the datas inside of running node.

Also this is out of cassandra question actually. So which way is better also? What is the advantages of installing applications as services instead of all-in-one (what is its name?) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally always install Cassandra using the tar ball. Simple, fast, and all the files are stored in the same place: the folder where you unzip the tar.

With recent versions of Cassandra, even data file folders are stored by default in the install folder if you don't change it in `cassandra.yaml`

The problem with installers like **apt-get** or **yum install** is that they follow some conventions. For example on Debian system, configuration files are stored at `/etc/cassandra` and binaries at `/usr/share/cassandra`

Comment: Yes Im on figuring out of it, can you eleborate also your answer a little more please?

Comment: Just donwload the zip file for Cassandra here http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ and unzip it to your server